# How to loop through all files in dir, run script, and write them into matching files in other dir

Tags: bash, zsh

I have files in a directory:

```
mkdir in_dir
echo 'a' > in_dir/file1.txt
echo 'b' > in_dir/file2.txt
echo 'c' > in_dir/file3.txt

mkdir out_dir
```

I have a command that takes input from files using `<` and writes output to a new file with `>`. I want to run it on all files in `in_dir` and write the output to `out_dir` under a matching file name.

This does the first part, runs a (dummy) command on each file.

```
#!/bin/zs
for file in in_dir/*;
(cat $file ; echo '1')
```

I'd like to have 'file1.txt' in out_dir with the content 'a1', 'file2.txt' with 'b1' etc.

Comment: echo "$(cat $file)1" > "out_dir/$file"

Comment: what is the content of `out_dir/file1.txt`?  `a` or `a1`?

Comment: a1, I acknowledge that this wasn't very clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `yourscript` which process the information if I understood well. And you can make another script as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=$'\n'

for i in `ls -1 ./dir_in` ; do
    ./yourscript "$(cat ./dir_in/$i)" > ./dir_out/$i
done

unset IFS
```

Don't forget to take this script `chmod +x` permission.